# Using labeller to add units to strip labels with ggplot2 and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am making faceted plots in ggplot2. The groups I am faceting by have names that should logically include units, and I'd like to automatically add these units to the strip labels without manually writing out a new vector with all the labels - i.e. replace labels of "1", "2", "3" with "1 mg", "2 mg", "3 mg". I was able to do this using code analogous to the simplified example below. But it's still a little clunky to have to define the label vector separately and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this within the labeller function itself? It seems like this would be a fairly common scenario so I was surprised not to find more examples of how others have done it online. Thanks in advance!

```
df <- tibble(
  group = factor(rep(1:3, times = 5)),
  output = sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE)
  )

labs <- paste(levels(df$group), "mg")
names(labs) <- levels(df$group)

df %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = output))+
  facet_wrap(vars(group), labeller = labeller(group = labs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a lambda or anonymous function in `labeller` you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = output))+
  facet_wrap(vars(group), labeller = labeller(group = ~ paste(.x, "mg")))
```

[image]

Comment: Your lambda function is much tidier than my global function.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for! I don't fully understand why it works and labeller(group = paste(group, "mg")) doesn't -- what do the ~ and .x do differently?

Comment: The difference is that we have to use `"a lookup table, a function taking and returning character vectors, or simply a labeller function" (see ?labeller)` on the right hand of `=`. In my approach I use a function, i.e. `~paste(.x, "mg")` is the same as `function(x) paste(x, "mg")`, just shorter. Of course could also do `function(group) paste(group, "mg")`. But simply using `paste(group, "mg")` will not work. Here you will get an error about `group` not found.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would typically modify the dataframe before creating the plot to do that. This might not be what you are looking for but I would think this is the most practical solution

```
df2 <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(
    group2 = paste(group, "mg")
  )

ggplot(df2) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = output)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(group2))
```

Comment: Thank you! I see your logic of this being the most straightforward way :)

Comment: Gregory's answer is the more 'on the nose' solution and probably more elegant. There is no good reason not to use an extra column tough as far as I can see. Anyhow I would suggest to accept Gregory's as it's the more direct answer for the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own labeller function, as described here:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html

For example,

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tibble(
  group = factor(rep(1:3, times = 5)),
  output = sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE)
)

unit_labeller <- function(string) {
  labeled_string <- paste(string, "mg")
  return(labeled_string)
}

df %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = output))+
  facet_wrap(vars(group), labeller = labeller(group = unit_labeller))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! The lambda function above is more efficient for what I'm doing today, but I like this solution for easy use across multiple graphs & as someone who's still learning R functions it's useful to see how you set this up